# Using ImageMagick, write the Creation Date, on the image

Tags: date, imagemagick

Currently I use these commands in order, to set:

a) On the filename the date and time
b) Create a padded space on the image
c) Put my Watermark on the created padded space.

I would like in the padded space, to be added the Creation date. Is that possible? An how this can happen?

```
  for pic in DSC*.*; do  exiftool "-FileName<CreateDate" -d  "${pic//.*}_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.jpg" "$pic"; done;
  for pic in DSC*.*; do convert -background black -extent 0%x0%+0+120 "$pic" "${pic//.*}-padded.jpg"; done;
  for pic in DSC*-padded.*;  do composite -dissolve 100% -gravity SouthEast /Data/PHOTOS/watermark_0.png "$pic" "${pic//.*}-marked.jpg"; done
```

Comment: See -annotate at https://imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#annotate

Comment: I found the solution. I will post it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The command use the " stat -c '%y' " to take the modified date that it is stored on the filesystem. Not all filesystems store the original creation date of the file. Therefore, I used the last modified date. Stat command can find any type of date, if it is stored on the filesystem, otherwise return none.

Then, using annotate imagemagick command, I write it on the image itself.

```
  for pic in DSC*.*; do  convert "$pic"  -pointsize 24 -fill white -undercolor '#00000080' -gravity SouthWest -annotate +10+20 "$(stat -c '%y' "$pic")" "${pic//.*}_dated.jpg"; done;
```

**Update**

Cause "stat -c" option gave me "today date" in many cases,
and because I add Creation or Modification dates in the filename,
I print the filename directly on the image in order to save the date, a much quicker option.

```
for pic in *.* ; do
   exiftool "-FileName<CreateDate" -d  "${pic//.*}_%Y %m %d_%H %M %S.jpg" "$pic"   &&   exiftool "-FileName<FileModifyDate" -d  "${pic//.*}_%Y %m %d_%H %M %S.jpg" "$pic" ; done;
```

and...

```
 for pic in DSC*.*; do  convert "$pic"  -pointsize 24 -fill white -undercolor '#00000080' -gravity SouthWest -annotate +10+20 "$pic" "${pic//.*}_dated.jpg"; done;
```